# Bash: cannot append to local array

Tags: arrays, bash, append, local

The following script works:

```
#!/bin/bash

func () {
  local VAR=( "${VAR[@]}" "$1" )
  echo "${VAR[@]}"
}

func test
```

Output:

```
test
```

After changing the way how the array is appended, the script starts producing the error:

```
#!/bin/bash

func () {
  local VAR+=( "$1" )
  echo "${VAR[@]}"
}

func test
```

Output:

```
local: line 4: local: `VAR+': not a valid identifier
test
```

Why?

Comment: works for me; what version of `bash` are you running? (`/bin/bash --version`)

Comment: Yup, cant reproduce here, you might have some thing that is defined as `func` an alias maybe or sourced in memory?

Comment: Guys, thanks for checking.
Today I discovered that it is related to bash version.

Cygwin with Bash 4.1.17(0) - not working.
CentOS 7 with Bash 4.2.46(2) - not working.
Ubuntu 19.10 with Bash **5.0.3(1)** - **working**.